# CRC16 checksum calculation: which one is correct?

Tags: c++, checksum, crc, modbus

Currently I'm working on [Modbus protocol](http://modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf), which requires a CRC checksum. I implemented three functions, generating different results:

1. CRC16_table: implemented based on modbus manual above page 114, this's a look-up-table way, but I didn't verify the table provided in the manual.
2. CRC16_modbus: implemented based on modbus manual page 112, this's a naive way
3. CRC16_origin: implemented based on [this article](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html) and have the same result with [this calculator](http://depa.usst.edu.cn/chenjq/www2/software/crc/CRC_Javascript/CRCcalculation.htm) at least.

My code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

static unsigned char auchCRCHi[] = {
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40
};

static char auchCRCLo[] = {
0x00, 0xC0, 0xC1, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x03, 0x02, 0xC2, 0xC6, 0x06, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x05, 0xC5, 0xC4,
0x04, 0xCC, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0xCD, 0x0F, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0x0E, 0x0A, 0xCA, 0xCB, 0x0B, 0xC9, 0x09,
0x08, 0xC8, 0xD8, 0x18, 0x19, 0xD9, 0x1B, 0xDB, 0xDA, 0x1A, 0x1E, 0xDE, 0xDF, 0x1F, 0xDD,
0x1D, 0x1C, 0xDC, 0x14, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0x15, 0xD7, 0x17, 0x16, 0xD6, 0xD2, 0x12, 0x13, 0xD3,
0x11, 0xD1, 0xD0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x30, 0x31, 0xF1, 0x33, 0xF3, 0xF2, 0x32, 0x36, 0xF6, 0xF7,
0x37, 0xF5, 0x35, 0x34, 0xF4, 0x3C, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0x3D, 0xFF, 0x3F, 0x3E, 0xFE, 0xFA, 0x3A,
0x3B, 0xFB, 0x39, 0xF9, 0xF8, 0x38, 0x28, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0x29, 0xEB, 0x2B, 0x2A, 0xEA, 0xEE,
0x2E, 0x2F, 0xEF, 0x2D, 0xED, 0xEC, 0x2C, 0xE4, 0x24, 0x25, 0xE5, 0x27, 0xE7, 0xE6, 0x26,
0x22, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0x23, 0xE1, 0x21, 0x20, 0xE0, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x61, 0xA1, 0x63, 0xA3, 0xA2,
0x62, 0x66, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xA5, 0x65, 0x64, 0xA4, 0x6C, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xAF, 0x6F,
0x6E, 0xAE, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0xAB, 0x69, 0xA9, 0xA8, 0x68, 0x78, 0xB8, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xBB,
0x7B, 0x7A, 0xBA, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0xBF, 0x7D, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xB4, 0x74, 0x75, 0xB5,
0x77, 0xB7, 0xB6, 0x76, 0x72, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xB1, 0x71, 0x70, 0xB0, 0x50, 0x90, 0x91,
0x51, 0x93, 0x53, 0x52, 0x92, 0x96, 0x56, 0x57, 0x97, 0x55, 0x95, 0x94, 0x54, 0x9C, 0x5C,
0x5D, 0x9D, 0x5F, 0x9F, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0x5A, 0x9A, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0x99, 0x59, 0x58, 0x98, 0x88,
0x48, 0x49, 0x89, 0x4B, 0x8B, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0x4E, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0x4C, 0x8C,
0x44, 0x84, 0x85, 0x45, 0x87, 0x47, 0x46, 0x86, 0x82, 0x42, 0x43, 0x83, 0x41, 0x81, 0x80,
0x40
};

unsigned short CRC16_table(char* message, int len)
{
    unsigned char uchCRCHi = 0xFF;
    unsigned char uchCRCLo = 0xFF;
    unsigned uIndex;
    while(len--)
    {
        uIndex = uchCRCHi ^ *message++;
        uchCRCHi = uchCRCLo ^ auchCRCHi[uIndex];
        uchCRCLo = auchCRCLo[uIndex];
    }
    return (((unsigned short)uchCRCHi << 8) | (unsigned short)uchCRCLo);
}

unsigned short CRC16_origin(char* message, int len)
{
    const unsigned short generator = 0xA001;
    unsigned short crc = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        crc ^= (unsigned short)(message[i] << 8);
        for(int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if((crc & 0x8000) != 0)
            {
                crc <<= 1;
                crc ^= generator;
            }
            else
                crc <<= 1;

        }
    }
    return crc;
}

unsigned short CRC16_modbus(char* message, int len)
{
    const unsigned short generator = 0xA001;
    unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        crc ^= (unsigned short)message[i];
        for(int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if((crc & 1) != 0)
            {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= generator;
            }
            else
                crc >>= 1;

        }
    }
    return crc;
}

int main()
{
    char message[] = {0x01, 0x06,0x00, 0x63, 0x04, 0x00};
    int len = 6;
    unsigned short temp1 = CRC16_table(message, len);
    unsigned short temp2 = CRC16_origin(message, len);
    unsigned short temp3 = CRC16_modbus(message, len);
    cout<<hex<<temp1<<endl;
    cout<<hex<<temp2<<endl;
    cout<<hex<<temp3<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Could anyone help me point out which one is correct? Based on what I read, I believe CRC16_origin is most likely right, but I'm still not sure because the other two are from an official manual; I'm stuck on this for almost a week, let me know if you have any advice, thanks!

Comment: This is no review service. If you have a **specific** problem, see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Look for a canonical example of message plus the expected checksum, to find out which is correct

Comment: The CRC16_table approach is similar to the CRC table I use for modbus, but until you know you need the speed of the table approach, go with the one that's easy to read and debug.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301, however, the two approach (table one and modbus original one) sometimes  even have different results, for example, when 'message[] = {0x01, 0x06,0x00, 0x63, 0x04, 0x80}', they are completely different. However, when 'message[] = {0x01, 0x06,0x00, 0x63, 0x04, 0x01}', results are opposite on low and high byte. Have you ever experienced this? What kind of table do you use?

Comment: Looks like you may have an [endian problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Your table may have been developed for a big endian CPU and if you are writing PC code you almost certainly have a little endian processor. Magic may happen if you swap the names of `auchCRCHi` and `auchCRCLo`, but then maybe not.

Comment: Yup. It's endian. Just compared your table to a 16 bit Windows implementation that's been running for about 20 years without any complaints. Second last codes in my table are 80 hi 81 lo, Your table is 81 hi 80 lo. While the table approach is faster than the compute everything approach, it does not port well.

Comment: @user4581301 you're awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Modbus uses an initial value of 0xffff.
- Your third example uses an initial value of zero, poorly enforced in their illiterate example.

They aren't going to deliver the same results. Stick with the Modbus code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, my original understanding was there is only one way to calculate CRC, if polynomial is the same, they have to generate same result, which, I suppose, is wrong.

Comment: @TonyLic : there is a myriad of ways to generate a CRC based on one polynomial. The top two differences that I can remember are : whether the bits are supposed to enter the algorithm LSB- or MSB-first, and the starting value of the algorithm (usually 0xFF...FF or 0). Unfortunately, descriptions of CRC algorithms frequently miss this, which practically leaves you with a guessing game when you have to actually implement one.

Answer (score 1):

Of the three approaches:

`CRC16_table` is correct, but only on a big endian CPU. In the old days a table-based approach would be the fastest approach, but it does not port between processors well.

`CRC16_origin` uses the wrong seed value. It computes a CRC for something, but not modbus.

`CRC16_modbus` is correct and portable.

With a modern processor the performance difference between the `CRC16_table` and `CRC16_modbus` approaches may not be worth the portability issues. Profile it and find out. On my PC they run neck-and-neck, which say go with the simplest and most portable. On an ARM or MSP430, who can say?

Experimental hack code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

uint16_t sizeeffect; // hack global to force execution of loops

static unsigned char auchCRCHi[] = {
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0,
0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01,
0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,
0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x81,
0x40
};

static unsigned char auchCRCLo[] = {
0x00, 0xC0, 0xC1, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x03, 0x02, 0xC2, 0xC6, 0x06, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x05, 0xC5, 0xC4,
0x04, 0xCC, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0xCD, 0x0F, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0x0E, 0x0A, 0xCA, 0xCB, 0x0B, 0xC9, 0x09,
0x08, 0xC8, 0xD8, 0x18, 0x19, 0xD9, 0x1B, 0xDB, 0xDA, 0x1A, 0x1E, 0xDE, 0xDF, 0x1F, 0xDD,
0x1D, 0x1C, 0xDC, 0x14, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0x15, 0xD7, 0x17, 0x16, 0xD6, 0xD2, 0x12, 0x13, 0xD3,
0x11, 0xD1, 0xD0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x30, 0x31, 0xF1, 0x33, 0xF3, 0xF2, 0x32, 0x36, 0xF6, 0xF7,
0x37, 0xF5, 0x35, 0x34, 0xF4, 0x3C, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0x3D, 0xFF, 0x3F, 0x3E, 0xFE, 0xFA, 0x3A,
0x3B, 0xFB, 0x39, 0xF9, 0xF8, 0x38, 0x28, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0x29, 0xEB, 0x2B, 0x2A, 0xEA, 0xEE,
0x2E, 0x2F, 0xEF, 0x2D, 0xED, 0xEC, 0x2C, 0xE4, 0x24, 0x25, 0xE5, 0x27, 0xE7, 0xE6, 0x26,
0x22, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0x23, 0xE1, 0x21, 0x20, 0xE0, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x61, 0xA1, 0x63, 0xA3, 0xA2,
0x62, 0x66, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xA5, 0x65, 0x64, 0xA4, 0x6C, 0xAC, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xAF, 0x6F,
0x6E, 0xAE, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0xAB, 0x69, 0xA9, 0xA8, 0x68, 0x78, 0xB8, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xBB,
0x7B, 0x7A, 0xBA, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0xBF, 0x7D, 0xBD, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xB4, 0x74, 0x75, 0xB5,
0x77, 0xB7, 0xB6, 0x76, 0x72, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xB1, 0x71, 0x70, 0xB0, 0x50, 0x90, 0x91,
0x51, 0x93, 0x53, 0x52, 0x92, 0x96, 0x56, 0x57, 0x97, 0x55, 0x95, 0x94, 0x54, 0x9C, 0x5C,
0x5D, 0x9D, 0x5F, 0x9F, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0x5A, 0x9A, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0x99, 0x59, 0x58, 0x98, 0x88,
0x48, 0x49, 0x89, 0x4B, 0x8B, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0x4E, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0x4C, 0x8C,
0x44, 0x84, 0x85, 0x45, 0x87, 0x47, 0x46, 0x86, 0x82, 0x42, 0x43, 0x83, 0x41, 0x81, 0x80,
0x40
};

unsigned short CRC16_table(char* message, int len)
{
    unsigned char uchCRCHi = 0xFF;
    unsigned char uchCRCLo = 0xFF;
    unsigned uIndex;
    while(len--)
    {
        uIndex = uchCRCHi ^ *message++;
        uchCRCHi = uchCRCLo ^ auchCRCHi[uIndex];
        uchCRCLo = auchCRCLo[uIndex];
    }
    return (((unsigned short)uchCRCHi << 8) | (unsigned short)uchCRCLo);
}

// CRC table I'm using for Wintell and PC linux
static const uint16_t lCRCTable[] =
{
    0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
    0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
    0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
    0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
    0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
    0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
    0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
    0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
    0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
    0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
    0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
    0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
    0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
    0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
    0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
    0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
    0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
    0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
    0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
    0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
    0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
    0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
    0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
    0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
    0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
    0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
    0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
    0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
    0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};

// CRC table I'm using for Wintell and PC linux
uint16_t CRC16 (const uint8_t *datap, size_t len)
{
    uint8_t loc;
    uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;

   while (len--)
   {
       loc = *datap++ ^ crc;
       crc >>= 8;
       crc ^= lCRCTable[loc];
   }
   return crc;
}

unsigned short CRC16_modbus(const char* message, int len)
{
    const unsigned short generator = 0xA001;
    unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        crc ^= (unsigned short)message[i];
        for(int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if((crc & 1) != 0)
            {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= generator;
            }
            else
                crc >>= 1;

        }
    }
    return crc;
}


int main()
{

    char message[] = "I am the very model of a modern major general.";

    uint16_t a = CRC16((uint8_t *)message, sizeof(message));
    uint16_t b = CRC16_modbus(message, sizeof(message));
    uint16_t c = CRC16_table(message, sizeof(message));

    if (a == b)
    {
        std::cout << "A-B Match"<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }

    if (a == c)
    {
        std::cout << "A-C Match"<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }

    int count  = 10000000;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (count--)
    {
        sizeeffect = CRC16((uint8_t *)message, sizeof(message));
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Table took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count() << "\n";

    count  = 10000000;
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (count--)
    {
        sizeeffect = CRC16((uint8_t *)message, sizeof(message));
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Calc took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count() << "\n";
}
```

Typical output:

```
A-B Match
5874
61974
Table took 900167
Calc took 892935
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answer, I should use `unsigned char*` as the first parameter instead of `char*` in my functions because when I convert it to `unsigned short`, if it's `char *` and MSB is 1, it will add `ff` for the high byte, which is obviously wrong!

Thanks everyone here! Solved!

Comment: Ha! That was funny timing.

Comment: Recommendation: rather than `unsigned char` and `unsigned short`, or even `char` and `short` when writing data protocol code, use fixed-size variables. Some of the standard data types, most notably `int` change size. End result is code that worked on one system goes goofy on others due to sign extensions and simply reading the wrong number of bits. Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer